# Rails Don't build twice an has_one relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have an has_one relationship between User and Wallet.

```
#User
 has_one :wallet

#Wallet
 belongs_to :user
 validates :user, allow_blank: true, uniqueness: true
 validates :key, presence: true
 validate :address, if: valid_address?

def valid_address?
 stuff
end
```

I would like to prevent re-build of a previously built wallet.

Because if I do User.last.build_wallet(key: "key1").save
I'll have in my db

```
id  key     address user_id created_at
1   test1   NULL    1       2015-04-06 09:38:54 2015-04-06 09:38:55
```

But if I rebuild the same way I'll have an second entry

```
id  key     address user_id created_at
1   test1   NULL    NULL    2015-04-06 09:38:54 2015-04-06 09:38:55
2   test1   NULL    1       2015-04-06 09:38:54 2015-04-06 09:38:55
```

It will add my a new entry and the user id is removed from the first one.

Answer (score 0):

Use `find_or_create_by_`

```
User.wallet.find_or_create_by_key("key1")
```

It will check if record already exist if not it will create a new one.

Answer (score 0):

See if the user already has a wallet and then build, like this:

```
wallet_attrs = {key: "key1"}
@wallet = User.last.wallet || User.last.build_wallet(wallet_attrs)
@wallet.save
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set validation in your model:

`validates_uniqueness_of :key, :message => "This key is already present."`